# Google Sheets Script - passing a range as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

In a google sheet, I have a custom function in a cell `=doSomething(myrange)`.
When using `myrange` directly in my script, it will return the values of the range as an array. In case I need not the content of the range but the range itself (e.g. to get cell colors) there is an option to parse the first parameter as a string and produce the range on the fly.

Example:

```js
    function doSomething(myRange) {
      let activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
      let activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
      let countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
      ...
```

Is there a more elegant way to retrieve the range and not the content of the range as an array? This would make the code much more readable.

Comment: OK, after trying to work with this above mentioned functionI chose to remove the script and work with standard google sheet formulas. The function was really unreliable.

Comment: I removed my custom function and replaced it with a standard formula. The function - even though very simple - did not work reliable. Using it at different rows in the spreadsheet produced sometimes correct, sometimes incorrect results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your range as a string in your custom function and use [Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

Instead of `=doSomething(A2:B3)` use `=doSomething("A2:B3")`

**Sample Code:**

```
function doSomething(myRange){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var bgColors = sheet.getRange(myRange).getBackgrounds()
  for (var i in bgColors) {
    for (var j in bgColors[i]) {
      Logger.log(bgColors[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return bgColors;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

- You can also specify which sheet you want to read the range as shown in the example output

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, you put a lot of effort into your answer and I appreciate this. However, this would not be my preferred solution since I have co-workers who would need an introduction to use this simple function and this would not be feasible.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without wrapping the range in quotation marks? I plan to copy this formula down too many cells.