# How to compare colors in Apps Script Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a custom function that checks if cells in a specific row, between certain columns have a Yellow background. However, the function is always returning `0`.

```js
function score(input) {
  var row = input;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  
  if (range.getCell(row, 4).getBackground == '#ffff00') {
    return (7);
  } else if (range.getCell(row, 5).getBackground == '#ffff00') {
    return (5);
  } else if (range.getCell(row, 6).getBackground == '#ffff00') {
    return (4);
  } else if (range.getCell(row, 7).getBackground == '#ffff00') {
    return (2);
  } else {
    return (0);
  }
}
```

[Example of code not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8LNI.png)

I'm guessing the problem is in how to compare two colors, but haven't found information about it.

I already used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231187/google-sheets-script-passing-a-range-as-a-function-parameter) answer before and the documentation for [getBackground](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground), but no luck yet. I also tried the includes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72638588/compare-texts-in-google-apps-script).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Read the documentation again](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground). It's a ***method*** not a property. `x.getBackground() == ...`

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan! Effectively that was the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RoryMcCrossan I found the error was using getBackground as a property and not a method (i.e. forgetting to add the () at the end).

Here is the corrected code:

```
function score(input) {
  var row = input;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  colorVal = '#ffff00'
  if (range.getCell(row, 4).getBackground() == colorVal){
    return (7);
  } else if(range.getCell(row, 5).getBackground() == colorVal){
    return(5);
    } else if(range.getCell(row, 6).getBackground() == colorVal){
    return(4);
    } else if(range.getCell(row, 7).getBackground() == colorVal){
    return(2);
  } else{
  return(0);
  }
}
```